# Large file parsing speedup

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

The file has 4 million lines. I get each line from the file using BufferedReader. Next, the resulting string is parsed using JSONObject and inserted into the database using room

How to get the maximum speed of this process?

So i get the string

```
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

coroutineScope.launch {

                    val inputStream: FileInputStream
                    val reader: BufferedReader
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        val currentFileReaderInfo = FileReaderInfo(file.nameWithoutExtension, 0)
                        inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                        reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                        var line: String? = reader.readLine()
                        while (line != null && !isStop) {
                            val newVal = line
                            fileReaderCommunication.lineInFile(
                                newVal,
                                currentFileReaderInfo
                            )
                            line = reader.readLine()
                        }
                       
                    }
                }
```

Parsing

```
 JSONObject(json).let { obj ->
        val shop = obj.optJSONObject("shop")?.let { shop ->
            Shop(
                shop.optBoolean("disableCardDiscounts"),
                shop.optString("shopId"),
                shop.optString("region"),
                shop.optString("default")
            )
        }

        val order = obj.optJSONObject("orders")?.let {
            Orders(
                total = it.optInt("total"),
                first = it.optString("first"),
                last = it.optString("last")
            )
        }
        val card = obj.optJSONObject("card")?.let {
            Card(
                number = it.optString("number"),
                discount = it.getDouble("discount"),
                sum = it.getDouble("sum")
            )
        }
        return CustomerData(
            obj.optString("id"),
            obj.optString("customerId"),
            shop,
            obj.optString("registerId"),
            order,
            card,
            createdAt = obj.optString("createdAt"),
            updatedAt = obj.optString("updatedAt"),
            createdDate = obj.optLong("createdDate"),
            updatedDate = obj.optLong("updatedDate")
        )
    }
```

Attempts to parallelize reading and parsing did not give much speed increase

Comment: Just making sure that you can't [use a pre-populated database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate)

Comment: You get the maximum speed by not parsing a 4 million line file.  That's ridiculously large.  At a minimum you should break it up to only process the parts you have to.  Or looking at this data, it should be a database and you should probably just dl the db directly.

Comment: You need to benchmark each major part of your process to know where you can potentially make gains.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `return` in "`return CustomerData(...)`"? That doesn't return to the enclosing `let`. It returns from the whole function.